# Dual Boot Windows 10 with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows

I have Windows XP and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed. I want to install fresh Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and Windows 10 and then want to remove Windows XP safely without harming data and previous version of Ubuntu. Can you please guide me regarding the safe procedure.

Update: Thanks for the answer. I am just updating details. I have 50 GB partitions and two are small partitions. Ubuntu is on separate 20 GB partitions. and I want to keep them as it is while wish to install Win10 in new unallocated space. If I do so, what will happen to WinXP and Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: If an older system using XP, then it has to be using the 35 year old BIOS/MBR configuration. New computers use UEFI/gpt. But Windows in BIOS boot mode has to boot from a primary NTFS partition with the boot flag. If you install Windows 10 in a logical partition, it has to put its boot files into the XP install as that has to be a primary partition. Best to see details of you partitions: `sudo parted -l` With MBR you can only have 4 primary partitions and one is usually the extended for more logical partitions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure, do you want to keep your Ub**u**ntu 14.04 installation?

I personally would just backup all my data, either on a second drive or on an extra partition. Then i would proceed with installing Win 10 by whiping the WinXP partition. This will overwrite your bootloader, so you won't be able to directly boot into Ubuntu 14.04.

Afterwards Ubuntu 16.04 can be installed on a ext4 partition, either on a new one or on the one used by 14.04.

Further advice can be given if you list your current partitions/harddrives.

Comment: If your answer requires further information from the OP, It's preferable to request that they [edit] their question to respond to your need for clarity. Question marks IMHO don't belong in answers. You might like to review http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer